# PhpMailer sends the registration form to the e-mail 3 times

Tags: phpmailer

The same registration form information comes to my mail more than once. 
My Mailbox is filled with exactly the same forms. 
Can you help me solve this problem?

PHP CODE:

```
  ﻿        <?php
    require("phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");
    $mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object

         $mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
                    $subject = "[XX] Registration Form";
                    $question = nl2br(stripcslashes($_POST['question']));
                    $question = trim($question);
                    $email_message = "<b>Name:</b> ".stripcslashes($_POST['fname'])."<br><br>";
                    $email_message .= "<b>Surname:</b> ".stripcslashes($_POST['lname'])."<br><br>";
                    $email_message .= "<b>Birthday:</b> ".stripcslashes($_POST['dob'])."<br><br>";    
$email_message .= "<b>Phone:</b> ".stripcslashes($_POST['phone'])."<br><br>";
$email_message .= "<b>Email:</b> ".stripcslashes($_POST['email'])."<br><br>";
$email_message .= "<b>Address:</b> ".stripcslashes($_POST['adres'])."<br><br>";
$email_message .= "<b>Location:</b> ".stripcslashes($_POST['Location'])."<br><br>";                              
                    $body = $email_message;
                    $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
                    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
                    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
                    $mail->Host = "smtp.yandex.com.tr";
                    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
                    $mail->Port = 465; // or 465
                    $mail->IsHTML(true);
                    $mail->CharSet  ="utf-8";
                    $mail->SetFrom("info@xx.com", "XX REGISTRATION FORM"); // Mail adresi

                    $mail->Username = "info@xx.com"; // Mail adresi
                    $mail->Password = "xxx"; // Parola
                    $mail->Subject = $subject;
                    $mail->body = $body;
                    $mail->MsgHTML($body);
                    $mail->AddAddress("info@xx.com");
                    $mail->addReplyTo(stripcslashes($_POST['emailer']), "");

                    if(!$mail->Send()){
                            echo "Mail Error".$mail->ErrorInfo;} else {            
                    echo "Mesaj Gönderildi";
                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved when I edited my codes like this.

The code executed when the form is submitted includes the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  function checkForm(form) // Submit button clicked
  {
    //
    // check form input values
    //

    form.myButton.disabled = true;
    form.myButton.value = "Please wait...";
    return true;
  }



</script>
```

While the HTML for the form itself looks something like:

```
<form method="POST" action="..." onsubmit="return checkForm(this);">
...
<input type="submit" name="myButton" value="Submit">

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely that the script is simply being run more than once. This can be caused by browser plugins, or by not preventing processing of empty forms. Protect against sending empty messages during page load by wrapping it in a condition like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['emailer'])) {
    //Rest of your script
```

The main thing to check first is whether a single run of your script is sending multiple messages, or whether the script is being run more than once (sending one message each time). Try writing something to a log file, or making it obvious in received messages by appending a random number to the end of the subject line. If you receive two messages with the same number in the subject, they are true duplicates; if the numbers are different subjects, your script is being run more than once:

```
$mail->Subject = 'Hi ' . rand();
```

Some other problems:

```
$mail->body = $body;
```

PHP is case-sensitive for properties, so that should be `$mail->Body = $body;`, but you're also calling `$mail->MsgHTML($body);`, which sets the `Body` property for you, so you don't need to set body yourself as well.

While you're working on a script, `$mail->SMTPDebug = 1` isn't very useful as it doesn't show what the server is saying; set `$mail->SMTPDebug = 2`. Don't forget to set it to 0 in production!

I can also see that you're using a very old version of PHPMailer, and have based your code on an obsolete example, so [update](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Comment: I tried the code you typed but it didn't work. Or I wrote it in the wrong order.

 if (isset($_POST['emailer'])) {
    //Rest of your script

Comment: When the submit button is clicked, the form does not give immediate feedback, so the clicker clicks 3-5 times to make sure it sends. He comes from the same mail more than once.

How can I solve this?

Comment: This is a common problem - SMTP is fundamentally unsuited to sending synchronously to remote destinations during form submission handling as it's often very slow. Submit to a local mail server and let it deal with onward delivery at its leisure, while you're then free to send a useful response back to the form submitter.